# Why My API Request always return unauthorized message

Tags: api, postman, zoho, zohobooks

I'm always getting the error code 57

**Method**

`GET`

**API**

`https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/organizations`

this is my setting

**Headers**

`Authorization Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.f494xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

**Return**

```
{
    "code": 57,
    "message": "You are not authorized to perform this operation"
}
```

Comment: Have you used the OAuth2 flow correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes error 57 is because the wrong server is queried.

For example, if an account is associated with `books.zoho.eu` but the query url is to `books.zoho.com` it will throw the 57 error.  So check for that.